# parsing err! 'return' outside of function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I wanted to add a unban command.
This my code so far:

```
if (command === ":unban") {
    if (!msg.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
        return msg.channel.send(`**${msg.author.username}**, You do not have perms to unban someone`);
    }
    
    if (!msg.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
        return msg.channel.send(`**${msg.author.username}**, I do not have perms to unban someone`);
    }
    
    let userID = args[0]
    msg.guild.fetchBans().then(bans=> {
        if (bans.size == 0) return 
        let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id == userID);
        if (!bUser) return
        msg.guild.members.unban(bUser.user);
    });
}
```

when I run it it gives me this error:

```
parsing error: 'return' outside of function
```

can somebody help me out on this because im new to this stuff

Comment: Hello! This error could also be caused by missing brackets, so please make sure you have no missing brackets

Comment: @abisammy not necessarily, if this code is as it is, it wont work. You can only return from an actual functions, just as it says in the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use a return function, with nothing to return to. Returning out of those if-cases is not possible. You could put that code in a separate function and call that, then returning would not bring an error. A simple rewrite of your code using a bool should fix the issue tho:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if(message.content === "!ping"){
    message.channel.send("pong")
  } else if(message.content === '!unban') {
    let permissionToKick = true;

    if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
      permissionToKick = false
      message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, You do not have perms to unban someone`)
    }

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
      permissionToKick = false
      message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, I do not have perms to unban someone`)
    }

    if(permissionToKick) {
      let userID = args[0] //args[] are not defined, and this will throw an error
        message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans=> {
        if(!bans.size === 0) {
          let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id === userID)
          if(bUser) {
            message.guild.members.unban(bUser.user)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

PS: I see you are using `args[]` in your code, but args are nowhere to be defined. I won't write all the code for you, since Stackoverflow is not Code-writing platform. I would advise you learn the basics of JavaScript and discord.js first.

A good source to learn JavaScript is [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/). If you understand the basics, I advise you to read the Documentation of [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) or follow the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin)

Comment: how can you aply it to an actual command like when a user says !unban it unbans the user, I have tried several thing like putting the code in a code like this: client.on("message", message => {
if(message.content === "!unban")
message.channel.send("the code that you fixed"
}
I have tried it that way but it doesn't work since I'm a complete noob at coding and just started if you could tell me how to implement my code you just fixed into an actual command, that would be very helpful.

Comment: the "message" event is also from an older version of discord.js. I edited my answer, so it should work now.

Comment: it still doesn't work, it said args is not defined.
is there any ways to fix this problem?

Comment: as I said, even in my comment: I know. Please learn the basics of JS and read the Guide. In the Guide everything is explained, better than I can do here.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there