# discord.js code error: args is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so I created a code to unban people but since I'm new in coding I have absolutely no idea how to make my code works, this is my code:

```
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if(message.content === "!ping"){
    message.channel.send("pong")
  } else if(message.content === '!unban') {
    let permissionToKick = true;

    if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
      permissionToKick = false
      message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, You do not have perms to unban someone`)
    }

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
      permissionToKick = false
      message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, I do not have perms to unban someone`)
    }

    if(permissionToKick) {
      let userID = args[0] //args[] are not defined, and this will throw an error
        message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans=> {
        if(!bans.size === 0) {
          let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id === userID)
          if(bUser) {
            message.guild.members.unban(bUser.user)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

can anyone fix this for me, I know I'm asking a bit much but I'm new in coding and I have no one to ask, please don't be mad

Comment: the entire code seems to be wrong, please take your time learning because its all wrong, you are even mixing v12 code with v13, you can always learn through [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs) and [guides](https://discordjs.guide)

Comment: I would recommend learning JavaScript before trying to write a Discord Bot. As mentioned by @UltraX, the code above makes no sense, for example why is the listener `messageCreate`? Go through [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/), then try and write a simple bot that sends a message. Work from there, and try to add more functionality before going straight into advanced commands.

Comment: You can't just copy the answer I gave you on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68918086/parsing-err-return-outside-of-fuction/68919057#68919057) and ask people to code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @JoeMoore the listener is correct, check the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate)

Comment: @ChristophBlüm this changed since v12, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define it. Try this:

```
const args = message.content.split(" ");
```

The final code would look like:

```js
  if(permissionToKick) {
      
      // Split the content in an array
      const args = message.content.split(" ");
      
        // args[0] would be the command so args[1] is the userID
        let userID = args[1] 
        message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans=> {
        if(!bans.size === 0) {
          let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id === userID)
          if(bUser) {
            message.guild.members.unban(bUser.user)
          }
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: Although this is technically correct, their code will still not work even if this is corrected.